# In Beyond Compare, how can I exclude file names with special characters?

Tags: mac, beyondcompare

In a Beyond Compare using a Folder Compare, I wish to exclude files that contain special characters. In particular I have files named Icon\r, Icon with a carriage return as the last character of the file name.

In Session Settings, Name Filters, I can not find a way to describe this file name in the "Exclude files:" list.

If I dump the characters for the filename, I can see it has a carriage return appended in the name:

```
bash-3.2$ mdls Icon*
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate = 2018-12-14 17:56:48 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate      = 2018-12-14 17:56:48 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode       = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags       = 16384
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon     = 0
kMDItemFSInvisible         = 1
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery      = 0
kMDItemFSLabel             = 0
kMDItemFSName              = "Icon "
kMDItemFSNodeCount         = 363549
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID      = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID       = 501
kMDItemFSSize              = 363549
kMDItemFSTypeCode          = ""
bash-3.2$ ls -1 | egrep Icon | od -c
0000000    I   c   o   n  \r  \n                                        
0000006
bash-3.2$ ls Icon*
Icon?
bash-3.2$
```

I have tried various representations "Icon ", "Icon\r" and would prefer to not use "Icon*", ie anything starting with Icon, which may exclude other files starting with Icon.

Comment: Try to right-click such a filename and use the “exclude” preference.

Comment: Tried that. It did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond Compare's filename filters don't support matching on carriage return or line feed. Filename filters use the wildcard ? to match on any single character. Try using the filename filter "Icon?" or "Icon??".